# MS Project 2010 - Ressources Use - Tasks Ordering

Tags: sorting, task, ms-project

I'm using MS Project 2010 (standard) for Project, time and planning management. (using Already used time, Work to do, and others things.)

For this I use 2 main views :

- Gantt Diagramm, where I list all my tasks, allocate Ressources and allocate charges
- Then, I switch to Ressources Use, where to check for my ressources if they are overcharged/undercharged

BUT

in the Ressource Use View, tasks are not sorted the same way I created it into Gantt View, and If I had a new task, it doesn't come the right "place", but at the end of the tasks allocated to this ressources...

Any Idea ?? Explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

I just understand that these are two independant views...
so I just use the Sort Function in the Ressources Use View, and then it goes :)